# Will Blazor always re-render the whole component?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-component

If some element inside a Razor component is updated by code, will the whole component re-render, or only the affected parts?

Comment: This question is too vague and the answer would be "it depends" - on how you write your component and what you are updating.

Comment: Blazor sends information about changes in the page to the client.  It will generally not re-send information that hasn't changed.  The opposite is usually more of a problem-- you have code that changes a variable-- but it doesn't necessarily update as expected.

Answer (score 2):

> will the whole component re-render, or only the affected parts?

When an event triggers on a Component then the *whole* component will be re-rendered in Blazors render-tree and the differences will be applied to the Browsers DOM.

What happens with sub-components depends on the parameters. When there are changed values or complex-type parameters then the sub-component will re-render too.